# controllers inside subfolder gives blank page

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

im having a small web app developed using Codeigniter and in my controller folder i have a separate folder which has the controllers related to the admin.

for an example when i try to access my site `http://example.com/panel/index.php?/admin/dashboard/home` i get a blank page. It happens with all the controllers inside the subfolder.

It works on my localhost but when i upload it to my hosting on Godaddy all i get is a blank page. No errors nothing.

Below is my folder structure

```
controller
----- admin
----------Login.php
----------Dashboard.php
----------Settings.php
------ user
----------Login.php
----------Dashboard.php
----------Settings.php
```

Can someone tell me what might be causing this?

Comment: try with out ? Administration `http://example.com/panel/index.php/admin/dashboard/home`

Comment: can you update post to show what is there in Dashboard.php  and it is loading view file or not

Comment: https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @Deep3015 i have just added an `echo` to test but when i move it outside of the folder it works

Comment: How you access your controller outside sub folder?

Comment: on my localhost i use `http://example.com/panel/index.php/admin/dashboard/home` and it works.. on godaddy i have to use `index.php?`

Comment: remove ?
 [http://example.com/panel/index.php?/admin/dashboard/home]

Answer (score 0):

The issue it with controller name

http://example.com/panel/index.php?/admin/Dashboard/home

```
Changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst and 
everything else in lowercase).
```

So you controllers and files name should be

My_controller (only M upper case rest lower case)